# httpd.pointsWrittenDropped in _internal

Tags: influxdb

I’m trying to understand all metric available in the _internal database.
I’ve found some documentation [here](https://github.com/influxdata/docs.influxdata.com/blob/4959e52c3b6e00042ec444dd5a8a8cf9a5049a93/content/influxdb/v1.0/troubleshooting/internal_statistics.md) (outdated) and of course [here](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/blob/master/monitor/README.md) but I still have some questions.

For example, do you know the difference between httpd.pointsWrittenDropped and httpd.pointsWrittendFail ?

I’m looking for detailed documentation on these metrics for quite a long time now but have not found anything. Some help would be very appreciable!

related to https://community.influxdata.com/t/httpd-pointswrittendropped-in-internal/4256